# Why can't I write to this div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried several methods of writing to this div, but to know avail:

The 'testing' works, but nothing else:

```
document.write("testing");
document.getElementById('menu2').innerHTML += "<br>Some new content!";
var node = document.getElementById("menu2");
node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Hello" + "</p>";
(function printMsg() {
    var node = document.getElementById("menu2");
    node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Hello World!" + "</p>";
})();
```

and in the html

```
<div id="menu2">x</div>
```

the x shows

As of this writing, this is at http://www.jchess.nyc (index page)

Answer (score 2):

That happens because `document.write` just writes the text you specify in body; it's not required for any element to be loaded to be able to `document.write`, but `document.getElementById()` searches for the element in DOM, which isn't created immediately when you begin executing your script, so your script is trying to access your element with id menu2 before it is loaded.

To be able to use `document.getElementById()`, you should wait for the DOM to load, by placing all your methods accessing DOM to:

```
window.onload=function(){

}
```

Comment: *"document.write just overwrites all your html in the <body>"*. In OP's case it doesn't happen, because `document` is still open (being rendered). So `document.write` just appends text to the document and doesn't overwrite body.

Comment: @dfd fair enough; edited.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that you put script in the begining of the body, so it's executed before `div#menu2` is avaialable in DOM.

The simplest fix is to move `script` tag before closing `</body>` tag. Also remove `document.write`, it's not a problem here but you don't need it.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('menu2').innerHTML += "<br>Some new content!";

var node = document.getElementById("menu2");
node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Hello" + "</p>";

(function printMsg() {
    var node = document.getElementById("menu2");
    node.innerHTML = "<p>" + "Hello World!" + "</p>";
})();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I would also cache the element at the beginning rather than pick it up at three different points in the code, but that's an aside.